# C: How to read portion of a file in chunks

Tags: c, file, openmp, chunks

I have to implement for a course assignment the Huffman encryption & decryption algorithm first in the classic way, then I have to try to make it parallel using various methods (`openMP`, `MPI`, `phtreads`). The scope of the project is not to make it necessarily faster, but to analyze the results and talk about them and why are they like that.

The serial version works perfectly. However, for the parallel version, I stumble with a reading from file problem. In the serial version, I have a pice of code that looks like this:

```
char *buffer = calloc(1, MAX_BUFF_SZ);

while (bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, MAX_BUFF_SZ, input) > 0) {
    compress_chunk(buffer, t, output);
    memset(buffer, 0, MAX_BUFF_SZ);
}
```

This reads at most `MAX_BUFF_SZ` bytes from the input file and then encrypts them. I used the `memset` call for the case when `bytes_read < MAX_BUFF_SZ` (maybe a cleaner solution exists though).

However, for the parallel version (using openMP for example), I want each thread to analyze only a portion of the file, but the reading to be done still in chunks. Knowing that each thread has and id `thread_id` and there are at most `total_threads`, I calculate the start and the end positions as following:

```
int slice_size = (file_size + total_threads - 1) / total_threads;
int start = slice_size * thread_id;
int end = min((thread_id + 1) * slice_size, file_size);
```

I can move to the start position with a simple `fseek(input, start, SEEK_SET)` operation. However, I am not able to read the content in chunks. I tried with the following code (just to make sure the operation is okay):

```
int total_bytes = 0;
while ((bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, MAX_BUFF_SZ, input)) > 0) {
    total_bytes += bytes_read;

    if (total_bytes >= end) {
        int diff = total_bytes - end;
        buffer[diff] = '\0';
        break;
    }

    fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, output);
    memset(buffer, 0, MAX_BUFF_SZ);
}
```

`output` is a different file for each thread. Even when I try with just 2 threads, there are some missing characters from them. I think I am close to the right solution and I have something like an error-by-one.

So the question is: *how can I read a slice of a file, but in chunks?* Can you please help me identify the bug in the above code and make it work?

**Edit**:
If `MAX_BUFF_SZ` would be bigger than the size of the input and I'll have for example 4 threads, how should a clean code look to ensure that `T0` will do all the job and `T1`, `T2` and `T3` will do nothing?

Some simple code that may be use to test the behavior is the following (note that is not from the Huffman code, is some auxiliary code to test things):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define MAX_BUFF_SZ 32

#define min(a, b) \
   ({ __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); \
       __typeof__ (b) _b = (b); \
     _a < _b ? _a : _b; })

int get_filesize(char *filename) {
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(f);
    fclose(f);

    return size;
}

static void compress(char *filename, int id, int tt) {
    int total_bytes = 0;
    int bytes_read;
    char *newname;
    char *buffer;
    FILE *output;
    FILE *input;
    int fsize;
    int slice;
    int start;
    int end;

    newname = (char *) malloc(strlen(filename) + 2);
    sprintf(newname, "%s-%d", filename, id);

    fsize = get_filesize(filename);
    buffer = calloc(1, MAX_BUFF_SZ);

    input = fopen(filename, "r");
    output = fopen(newname, "w");

    slice = (fsize + tt - 1) / tt;
    end = min((id + 1) * slice, fsize);
    start = slice * id;

    fseek(input, start, SEEK_SET);

    while ((bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, MAX_BUFF_SZ, input)) > 0) {
        total_bytes += bytes_read;
        printf("%s\n", buffer);

        if (total_bytes >= end) {
            int diff = total_bytes - end;
            buffer[diff] = '\0';
            break;
        }

        fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, output);
        memset(buffer, 0, MAX_BUFF_SZ);
    }

    fclose(output);
    fclose(input);
}

int main() {
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int tt = omp_get_num_threads();;
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        compress("test.txt", id, tt);
    }
}
```

You can compile it with `gcc test.c -o test -fopenmp`. You may generate a file `test.txt` with some random characters, more than 32 (or change the max buffer size).

**Edit 2**:
Again, my problem is reading a slice of a file in chunks, not the analysis per se. I know how to do that. It's an University course, I can't just say "IO bound, end of story, analysis complete".

Comment: Threading the read will not make it any faster. Totally useless.

Comment: The scope of the project is not to make it faster, but to analyze the results and talk about why it is not faster. Also, in the example I'm threading the read only for debug purposes, the real version does also the encryption in parallel, so each thread will encrypt a piece of the file and then I'll merge them. Please read the entire post :)

Comment: `buffer[diff] = '\0';` - this is wrong. Think of when `total_bytes` is exactly equal to `end`. The `diff` will be zero. So, then you want to keep the whole buffer, and you also want to write it to the output file, which you don't at the moment.

Comment: Also, you want to compare `total_bytes + start` to the `end`, not just `total_bytes` (assuming you did the initial `fseek`).

Comment: @kfx Yeah, I forgot to add the `fwrite` in that `if` (to write the remaining bytes); I also changed the checking to be like `int diff = total_bytes - end; buffer[total_bytes - diff] = '\0';` but there are still some problems.

Comment: Doing file-I/O from multiple threads is going to lead to race conditions, unless properly synchronized. Note that though C requires any individual stream operation to be protected by a lock, a combination of stream operations (especially on multiple streams, like your input and output) is *not* automatically serialized.

Comment: @EOF Since each thread will open the file individually and each of them will write to a partial individual file (with a different name), I don't think race conditions will occur. Of course, you can use a single opened file and parallelize everything much nicer, but that's some future work :)

Comment: `while (bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, MAX_BUFF_SZ, input) > 0) {` has the classic error. (Hint: look up operator precedence)

Comment: Don't know what's there to analyse. An IO bound task is IO bound, end of story, analysis complete. Encryption is probably going to be much faster than disk IO too, but if you want to be absolutely sure, just measure a single thread.

Comment: @n.m. Again, my problem was reading a slice of a file in chunks, not the analysis per se. I know how to do that. It's an University course, I can't just say "end of story, analysis complete".

Comment: You should mention that it is a course assignment in the text of the question, to save hours of fruitless talk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I just had to take a pen and a paper and make a little scheme. After playing around with some indices, I came out with the following code (`encbuff` and `written_bits` are some auxiliary variables I use, since I am actually writing bits to a file and I use an intermediary buffer to limit the writes):

```
while ((bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, MAX_BUFF_SZ, input)) > 0) {
        total_bytes += bytes_read;

        if (start + total_bytes > end) {
            int diff = start + total_bytes - end;
            buffer[bytes_read - diff] = '\0';
            compress_chunk(buffer, t, output, encbuff, &written_bits);
            break;
        }

        compress_chunk(buffer, t, output, encbuff, &written_bits);
        memset(buffer, 0, MAX_BUFF_SZ);
}
```

I also finished implementing the openMP version. For small files the serial one is faster, but starting from 25+MB, the parallel one starts to beats the serial one with about 35-45%. Thank you all for the advice.

Cheers!